# When should a Spring MVC controller method have @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use the `@ResponseBody` annotation with my Spring controller but I'm not sure when to use it. Also, I named my method `index`and I wonder if that matters. My method head is

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addproduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                              @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestParam("desc") String desc,) {
```

But in another method in the same controller I use the `@ResponseBody` and I want to know when that usage is correct:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView start() {
```

Can you please tell me? The functionality is working but I want to be sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use @ResponseBody, controller will convert the content you returned into the response body by HttpMessageConverter.

Usually, you can use it when you want to return specific data format(like json or xml). Here is a sample:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addproduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                            @RequestParam("desc") String desc,) {
           return "{\"name\": \"" + name + "\"}";
    }
```

Then, you can get a response : {\"name\": \"xxxxxx\"}"

Comment: what's happening when the return type is not a String but a ModelView (this look like a mistake to combine @ResponseBody and return a ModelView) ?  Which message HttpMessageConverteris used ?

Comment: depend on which converter you set in file springMVC-servlet.xml. If you use MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter. The converter will try to convert the object to json and return.

Comment: with the default configuration which converter will be used ?

Comment: HttpMessageConverter is an converter interface. There are 7 implemented converters. Which should be used, decide by several conditions: converter register list, accept type in request header and so on. Maybe this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) can help you know more about HttpMessageConverter.