# Spring MVC & JQuery AJAX Post only working with @ResponseBody

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a button in a HTML page with JQuery 1.8.
I'm using Spring MVC 4.1 to handle the requests.

```
      var test= "foo";
      $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            async : false,
            url : "rest/ping",
            data : JSON.stringify(test),
            dataType : "json" ,
            contentType : "application/json",
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown + " -- " + jqXHR.responseText);

            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("bar");
            }
        });
```

The Spring side:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class DummyController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/ping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void ping(@RequestBody String test) throws ServiceException{
    // nothing of concern
}
}
```

If I remove the @ResponseBody the system cannot find the mapping. If I add '(required=false)' to the request body annotation then the mapping is found but the ajax call fails because after the mapped url is called, the system calls "test/rest/ping/rest/ping".

If you have a documentation of JQuery and Spring MVC working together, please add them to this question. I'm not able to find a valid example describing exact this strange behaviour.
If you have any questions, please ask.
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the entire controller? It can be that there is an inconsistency with the annotation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ResponseBody` is needed since you are making an XHR call via JQuery. This is true for endpoints that will return a specific data format (JSON, XML) but also for endpoint that do not return any data (`void`).

Otherwise, when not specified Spring require a [ModelView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) object to be returned that will point to a specific view and can be decorated with a model hash in it.

In your case the problem could be that during `JSON.stringify(test)` your are not providing a valid key-value pair in the form of: 
`test=yourValue`

For more info about Responsebody you can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089421/when-should-a-spring-mvc-controller-method-have-responsebody).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following changes

Remove the controller's @RequestMapping("/test"). If you still want to keep it then include that as well in the AJAX as test/rest/ping